# tinyMCE won't remove underline formating

Tags: javascript, formatting, tinymce

in our app we have a tinyMCE text editor and have it inserting  tags for underline.  Recently, the app encountered a bug where we could select text, underline it, and save it just fine.  However clicking back into the same text field, and attempting to removing underlining (by selecting the underlined text, and clicking underline again) will not remove the formatting.  Further, when the tinyMCE field is initialized, it looks like it's converting our  tags to field contents here.  Any ideas what's going on here, at a minimum we would like to at least be able to remove the formatting.  Thanks!

Comment: can you describe this scenario using an example string and example formatting + a tinymce fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this late last night.  I needed to use inline_styles: true in my config object for the tinyMCE init.